# Lower Bound on Real Part of product?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

For complex vectors $u,z,a\in\mathbb{C}^n$, are there any interesting lower bounds on the quantity
$$
\Re\left[(a^*z)^2(u^*a)^2\right]
$$
in terms of $|a^*z|^2, |u^*a|^2$ that are tighter than
$$
\Re\left[(a^*z)^2(u^*a)^2\right] \geq -|a^*z|^2|u^*a|^2?
$$
I tried using the polarization identity but couldn't see any way to clean up all the terms.